# (Closed) Global variables are not picked up in a different function in python

Tags: python, global-variables

I am trying to make a code that rolls 2 dice and has some other requirements to look for. I have declared a variable as global but it is still giving me an error

I have also tried to put the variables as a condition in the draw() function but this will still not work

```
class DiceGame():    
  def game():
    global p1total
    global p1total
    p1total = 0
    p2total = 0
    i=1
    for i in range(1,5):
        dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
        dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
        dice3 = random.randint(1,6)
        dice4 = random.randint(1,6)
        dice5 = random.randint(1,6)
        dice6 = random.randint(1,6)

        if (dice1+dice2)%2 == 0:
            if p1total >= 10:
                p1total -+10
            else:
                p1total = 0
        else:
            p1total += 5
        if dice1==dice2:
            p1total += dice1+dice2+dice3

        if (dice4+dice5)%2 == 0:
            if p2total >= 10:
                p2total -+10
            else:
                p2total = 0
        else:
            p2total += 5
        if dice4==dice5:
            p2total += dice4+dice5+dice6
        i+=1
    DiceGame.draw(p1total, p2total)
  def draw(p1total, p2total):
    print("Player 1 has:",p1total)
    print("Player 2 has:",p2total)
    if p1total==p2total:
        p1dice = random.randint(1,6)
        p1total+=p1dice
        p2dice = random.randint(1,6)
        p2total+=p2dice
        DiceGame.draw()
    elif p1total > p2total:
        print("Player 1 wins with",p1total)
        print("Player 2 lost with",p2total)
        DiceGame.scores()
    elif p1total < p2total:
        print("Player 2 wins with",p2total)
        print("Player 1 lost with",p1total)
```

error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "", line 1, in 
        DiceGame.game()
      File "C:/Users/fredd/Desktop/dan/Dice game controlled assessment min 
    lines.py", line 61, in game
        DiceGame.draw()
      File "C:/Users/fredd/Desktop/dan/Dice game controlled assessment min 
    lines.py", line 63, in draw
        print("Player 1 has:",p1total)
    UnboundLocalError: local variable 'p1total' referenced before assignment

I just need the variables to be available to the draw() function and output the winner

Comment: For one, you have `global p1total` twice, you never declare `global p2total`. Secondly, you need to paste the errors into your question so we can help you debug the issue.

Comment: _I have declared a variable as global but it is still giving me an error_ You're making us guess what the error is.  Show us the error.

Comment: @RandomDavis thanks i must have missed that. It is working now.

Comment: Why are they globals at all, rather than instance attributes?

Comment: @chepner because at the time i didnt know there was a funtion __init__ to be able to do that. Now i do and it has made it a lot easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a mistake on my part where i didnt define the variables correctly in the global statements!